# C: Read words and include \n on them, but not spaces

Tags: c, string, file, fgets, scanf

I need to read from a file in C and put every word on an array,
spaces should not be included on the word (when it reaches a space it should end copying that word), but \n MUST BE INCLUDED whenever it is found.

```
fscanf(arquivo,"%s",palavras[i].string);
```

is almost working, but it is not including \n when it is found on the file..

```
fgets (temp , 100 , arquivo);
```

doesn't work because it doesn't stop when it finds a space.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Simplest is to read character-by-character using getc() and a small finite state machine.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` will, in this case, stop when it reaches ANY kind of whitespace (including newlines). You can try using `fgets` to read an entire line (including the newline), then use `strtok` iteratively to break it up.

For example:

```
char temp[100];
char *tok;

fgets (temp , 100 , arquivo);
while ((tok = strtok(temp, " ")) != NULL) {
    // 'tok' points to a null-terminated word with no spaces
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fscanf you could use the following:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^ ]", str);
```

Comment: just for explanation: this format string tells scanf to read until it finds a space.

Comment: But if I have a file like this:

one two three\nthree two one

there is a \n after the first three, but won't it keep reading until it finds another space? So my third string will be "three\nthree". Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes that's right, so I guess you want the second "three" as a new word?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` like,

```
ptr = NULL;
ptr = fgets (temp , 100 , arquivo); 
 // Check 1) return value for NULL 2) whether temp has `\n`
 // or read till `\n`

while( ( found = sscanf( ptr, "%s", palavras[i].string ) ) == 1 )
{
    // palavras[i].string has valid string

    ptr += strlen( palavras[i].string ); // next string in
    i++; // next element in array. Overflowing ?
}

strcat( palavras[i].string, "\n" );
```

Give enough size `fgets` to hold the line. Of course, more error checks are needed to make it stable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be while it equals 1? Since `sscanf` returns the number of items successfully read? Also, wouldn't `sscanf` just skip the newline anyways?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen THanks, fixed `while` loop. Good catch. Need some time to fix others.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Code is fixed. More error checks needed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach to this.

```
int fd,i,j=0;;
fd = open("nameoffile",O_RDONLY);
char buf[128], word[64];
char *words[128];

while (n=read(fd,buf,sizeof(buf))){
     memset(word,0,sizeof(word));
     for (i=0;i<n;i++){
         if (buf[i] != ' ') word[i] = buf[i];
         else {
              words[j] = malloc(sizeof(word));
              words[j] = word;
              j++;
         }
     }
}
```

This will create an array of character arrays (or strings), and add characters to each array until it finds a space, in which case it will skip it and move on to the next character and start a new string.